# HIVE - INSERT into table using WITH CLAUSE

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

```
with cte AS ( SELECT cust_id, COUNT(cust_id) OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id) cnt,collect(named_struct('id', concat(cast(split(acct_id,'_')[0] as string),"_",acct_type),'name', cast(acct_name as string))) as acct_list 
              FROM table_name1
              )
INSERT INTO table table_staging 
select cust_id,acct_list
FROM cte
WHERE cnt >=1 ;
```

is the insert query placed at correct position? it says -cannot recognize input near 'g' 'select' 'cust_id' in statement
also it shows below error sometimes while correcting few things
SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 1:89 Invalid function 'collect'

Comment: Not an answer, but using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` does not, in general, make any sense, because you are not telling Hive _which_ 10 records you actually want to insert.

Comment: i want to insert all the records , i will remove the limit but still i get the issue. pls help

Comment: It seems that your syntax is not correct. Have a look here :https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.6.5/bk_data-access/content/hive-013-feature-common-table-expressions.html



After you figure it out, please post and accept the answer to your own questions for others to use in the future :)

Comment: thanks for the above link. syntax is correct but the problem is with collect function--SemanticException [Error 10011]: Line 1:127 Invalid function 'collect'. not sure if there is any alternative function for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You overall syntax is fine.  Hive accepts CTEs with `INSERT` statements, preceding the `INSERT` as with a `SELECT`.

However, there is no `collect()` function.  Presumably you intend with [`collect_set()` or `collect_list()`](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF)).